# SQLite - Replace() set to match whole word not part of it

Tags: sqlite

In a column there are entries as `US` and entries such as `USA`. I'd like to replace all 'US' with 'USA'. when I tried:

```
replace(table.column, 'US', 'USA')
```

It replaces all `US` entries with USA, and all `USA` entries with `USAA`.

I've searched this a bit, and found some solution for *SQL* that could also work on ***SQLite***, but they suggest to use the `WHERE` clause.

**Is there any way to simply tell replace to work only on whole words?**

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: How are you using SWLite, e.g. from Android, Python, etc.?  You really need regex replacement to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a condition:

```
..........
replace(table.column, 'US', 'USA')
...............................
where table.column not like '%USA%'
```

or:

```
replace(replace(table.column, 'US', 'USA'), 'USAA', 'USA')
```

to restore back to 'USA' if a wrong replacement occurred.

Comment: My understanding of the OP is that `US` may occur inside a sentence.  So `US is the USA` should become `USA is the USA`.

Comment: This is covered by my 2nd solution.

Comment: ok, I wanted to avoid to put a where clause, or to double replace... but I'm really a noob with SQLite, if you guys tell me there's no way to specify a "whole word match" inside the replace() function itself... I'll work around with your suggestion... Thank you

Comment: A "whole word match" can be many things like: "something US something", "US", "something US.", "something US, something", "something US:" etc. If you don't want to use a WHERE clause use my 2nd solution, provided there are no valid `USAA` strings in your column.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually safeguard against this by adding spaces around the search word, as well as the replacement word:

```
replace(' ' + table.column + ' ', ' US ', 'USA').
```

something like this

Comment: Thank you Paulo, that was actually my first guess, but unfortunately there is data in which the word 'US' occurs by itself, and no spaces around it.

Comment: Can't you add spaces then trim after replace?